# lm() output doesnt make sense too small

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

using

```
lm(LAVG$RowMeans~LAVG$date)
```

both are names of columns in df i want to regress. i have used `abline()` further up that shows line of best fit with visible slope, but the outputs im getting for the slope doesnt match that, its extremely small exponent:

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  LAVG$RowMeans
1.448e+09      1.162e+06

i have another df i am doing the same with and getting the same issue. any ideas?

[image: for LAVG for example]

[image: here i get similarly small slope values, and this is far steeper]

values i get for this are using the same code , getting Coefficients:

(Intercept)    HAVG$date
7.241e+00    5.721e-09 .

Appreciate any thoughts thank you!

Comment: getting the same for a similar set i have and the slope on that is steeper than the on ein the above pic

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    HAVG$date  
  7.241e+00    5.721e-09

Comment: I don't understand the issue? The fitted lines look fine for the data provided.  I don't think your model is appropriate but honestly for what you gave to the model the slopes seem appropriate.

Comment: What date type is `LAVG$date`? Perhaps you are calculating the daily change vs. the annual change (which could be done by converting dates to a decimal year)?

Comment: so the plotted line is fine, its the values i get with that lm() function that im not sure how to make sense of. This is telling me my m coefficient is 3.498e-08 no? 

LAVG$date is double, theyre weekly values over the span of 5years. 

(i am pretty new to R so you might have to really dumb it down for me)

Comment: yes, `as.numeric([date variable])` puts it into seconds: `as.numeric(Sys.time())
[1] 1614895880`

Comment: so to confirm, in both tables i have dates from 01-01-2015 to 25-12-2020 on a weekly basis, and this chart is plotting average weekly price of a stock with that time series. Sounds reasonable to me that that may be causing an issue?